# Hide container by setting width=0, but occasionally some of the elements within the container briefly stay visible after the container hides

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry the FPS is a little rough, but basically I have created a side panel for some of my web app's settings

I open and close it by setting the width of a container element

```
document.getElementById("theSidePanel").style.width = "50vw";
```

and

```
document.getElementById("theSidePanel").style.width = "0";
```

If you look closely, when the panel closes, some of the controls on the panel stay visible for a second, and then disappear, after the side panel has already closed

I'm hoping that this has something to do with closing the panel by setting the width, is there a better way to do this?

Otherwise it'll be a bug somewhere else in code, which would be significantly more difficult to troubleshoot (If anybody has ideas, I'm all ears)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the browser is reducing the width to 1 (which I presume has a CSS transition on it), it will be repeatedly re-drawing and re-rendering the interior of the div as it shrinks and shrinks, which is probably causing the bug.

If the div is absolute or fixed-positioned, why not instead try keeping the width constant, and modifying the `left` property to negative the width of the div, and adding a transition to `left` to animate it? That will replicate the desired effect, but will not force the browser to continually re-render the div's contents.

Comment: holy cow, that worked perfectly, thank you!  I thought this was going to be much harder than it was